# PDF-XChange Editor SDK to merge multiple PDF with VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

Im trying to merge multiple PDF files into a single one... and thanks to a snippet i found on the support forums from the PDF-XChange, i was able to do it. Problem is it only allows me to do it once. After that it generates an error, like if something was left open.

**If i close the excel file** (its where im developing the code), **i can execute the routine again (once)**.

The error i get is:

[image]

The error is generated in the method `Doc.WriteToFile`

For the sake of testing, i created a simple routine:

```
Public Sub CreateDoc()
    Dim PXC As New PXC_Inst
    Dim Doc As IPXC_Document
    
    'Initialize
    PXC.Init ""
    
    'Create new document, save as pdf
    Set Doc = PXC.NewDocument()
    Doc.WriteToFile "c:\users\syntax\desktop\Test.pdf"
    
    'Close document and Finalize
    Doc.Close
    PXC.Finalize
End Sub
```

Below its the required reference (after installing the PDF-XChange Core API SDK):

[image]

**Could anyone kindly give me a hint** on this matter?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters this post, the solution i found to make it work is by calling the `INIT` and `FINALIZE` methods of the `PXC_Inst`, when excel starts and exits respectively.