# PDF Exchange Active X VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, editor, exchange-server, activex

i am trying to intilize PDF exchange Editor active X in VBA but unable to create an instance any help would be appreciated, code taken from below post
[PDF-XChange Editor SDK to merge multiple PDF with VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484263/pdf-xchange-editor-sdk-to-merge-multiple-pdf-with-vba-excel)

```
Public Sub CreateDoc()
Dim PXC As PXC_Inst
Dim Doc As IPXC_Document

'Initialize
PXC.Init ""
Set PXC = New PXC_Inst

'Create new document, save as pdf
Set Doc = PXC
Doc.WriteToFile "c:\users\syntax\desktop\Test.pdf"

'Close document and Finalize
Doc.Close
'PXC.Finalize
End Sub
```

[error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lf2d.jpg)

Comment: You cannot call `Init()` when the `PXC` object is nothing. Swap to have the `Init` method below the `PXC` object instantiation.

Comment: yes tried that too but it now says class not registered error, your help will be really appreciated